# Using a transistor as a switch

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega

I am attaching a motor to a atmega32 chip. I want to build an H-birdge but before doing that, I want to control the motor using the chip. I bought few NPN Transistors from RadioShack. 
I have 5V running though the breadboard. I attached Vcc to the Collector, Base to the Pin, and Emitter to the motor. And other wire of motor is hooked up to Ground. Unfortunately,  the power coming out of the transistor is too low, the motor is barely moving (As oppose when I hook up my motor straight to 5V). What is wrong? Do I need a different transistor or is my setup wrong? If it is the transistor, can you please recommend me the right one, I am not too good at those.

Thanks in advance!